# Prevent percentage height from increasing when the browser navigation bars are hidden in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image where its height is set to a percentage value (e.g. `60%`).

the problem is that in Safari browser when the browser navigation bars are hidden due to the user scrolling the image height increase (which I don't want).

I've also tried to use `vh` unit instead of percentage (but the issue is still not solved)

notice in the below image (side 2) how the height of the image increased when the navigation bars are hidden.

Is there any CSS or JavaScript trick to make image height `60%` of screen height (but doesn't change when the top and bottom navigation bars are hidden)

[image]

Comment: Maybe provide a max-height to the image so that it doesn't scale beyond the set height

Comment: @the.marolie `max-height` will not solve this issue. because I can't set it to a `px` value since I want the image to be `60%` of screen. and if I set it to a percentage value (e.g. `60%`) that also will not solve the issue since the viewport height change when the navs are hidden.